# Wordpress future posts sorting, newest on top

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have a wordpress (v. 3.8) loop that shows 5 future posts:

```
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=5&post_type=events&post_status=future&orderby=date&order=ASC'.'&paged='.$paged); 

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

The posts (custom post type "events") are sorting with the "planed" date but i want the newest created post to be on top.

Comment: How about trying with 'orderby=modified'  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best feature that every WP programmer should know is the ability to schedule his posts in WordPress. This feature can do more then letting you schedule your post to publish at a certain time.

BUT: there is one caveat using the `future` posts display - **there is no valid** `DATE` **field to sort on** as the date for those `future` posts **is not yet** `SET`.

You could try however with `orderby=ID` / `orderby=modified` and `order=ASC` (of course, assuming the sequence in your future posts by ID is the same sequence as their future dates).

Comment: aaaaah okay - "orderby=modified" is way better than orderby=ID, thanks so much, never heard of it :) i think this solves all my problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
orderby=ID
```

Did the job. The only question is: when i re-plan a post, how can i move it to top?

Comment: You can't (well, unless you change the post's ID), simply create a new post and move on.